# I am using xlpagertabstrip . I want to send some data from parent to childviewcontroller regularily after viewcontroller are loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

How do I communicate from parent to child view controller once a view is loaded? I want to communicate from parent to child without notification any idea?. from child to parent I can use protocol and delegates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegation` but there is no need of doing it, you can directly access the child `viewControllers` from the parent `viewController`. 
as we know that we can access all the child viewController from parent viewController.

```
let viewControllersArray = self.childViewControllers
let viewController = viewControllersArray[index] as? YouViewController
```

or if you dont know the index of your viewController

```
let viewControllersArray = self.childViewControllers
for viewController in viewControllersArray {
      if let viewController as? YouViewController {
                // your stuff
      }
}
```